# autocomplete input box with jquery ajax but want to store coressponding id in any other field

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I have an input box (name : state_name id : state_name) which is autocompleted with jquery and ajax.I am using "bsn.AutoSuggest_2.1.3" jquery plugin.
This is the html.

```
<input type="text" name="state_name" id="state_name" />
<input type="text" name="s_n_state" id="s_n_state"  value="<?=$letter_1?>"/>
```

This is the jquery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var options = {
        script:"includes/search_state.php?json=true&limit=6&",
        varname:"state_name",
        json:true,
        shownoresults:false,
        maxresults:6,
        callback: function (obj) { document.getElementById('s_n_state').value = obj.id; }
};
var as_json = new bsn.AutoSuggest('state_name', options);
</script>
```

Below is search_state.php code -

```
<?
include_once 'connection.php';
header("Content-Type: application/json");
    $state_name = $_GET['state_name'];
        echo "{\"results\": [";
        $arr = array();
        $result = mysql_query("select * from states where state_name like '%$state_name%'") or die(mysql_error());
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {
            $arr[] = "{\"id\": \"".$row['state_id']."\", \"value\": \"".$row['state_name']."\"}";
                }
        echo implode(", ", $arr);
        echo "]}";
?>
```

I am getting the response from ajax when I see it in console of browser but it is not visible in web page and also I want to store state_id from response to **s_n_state** input box so I can use it.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with autocomplete. My workaround was to store the state_id using delimited character concatenated with the other value.e.g "key:value". On the server side, simply parsed it out. Presumably, no other delimiting character in your key or value. It's not the most elegant but works great for most of my situation.